# How to select rows where multiple columns have same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a sql server table named myTbl like this:

```
BookID  PageID  textID    Date          Remarks
1       4       9         21-12-2017    1 
2       5       10        15-12-2017    1
3       6       11        13-12-2017    1
4       7       12        11-12-2017    1
2       5       10        22-12-2017    1
4       7       12        18-12-2017    1
```

I want to group the rows when BookID, PageID and textID have same values and show the result based on the most recent date ascending. For instance 4th & 6th row and 2nd & 5th row.

What I need is:

```
BookID  PageID  textID    Date           Remarks
1       4       9         21-12-2017     1
2       5       10        15-12-2017     1
2       5       10        22-12-2017     1
3       6       11        13-12-2017     1
4       7       12        11-12-2017     1
4       7       12        18-12-2017     1
```

How I want to write is:

```
SELECT *
FROM booksdb.dbo.books 
GROUP BY BookID, PageID, textID Order by Date
```

I want all the columns in the table where BookID, PageID, textID are same and arranged by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `group by`, Because there is not any *aggregate function* in your query.
 you can try to use `RANK` with *window function*  to make row_number then order by the number.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   BookID INT,
   PageID  INT,
   textID  INT,
   DATE  DATE,
   Remarks INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1,4,9 ,'2017-12-21',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,5,10,'2017-12-15',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (2,5,10,'2017-12-22',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3,6,11,'2017-12-13',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,7,12,'2017-12-11',1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (4,7,12,'2017-12-18',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY BookID, PageID, textID Order by Date) rn
  FROM T
)
SELECT BookID,PageID,textID,[DATE],Remarks
FROM CTE
ORDER BY BookID, PageID, textID,rn
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9133d/5/0)**:

```
| BookID | PageID | textID |       DATE | Remarks |
|--------|--------|--------|------------|---------|
|      1 |      4 |      9 | 2017-12-21 |       1 |
|      2 |      5 |     10 | 2017-12-15 |       1 |
|      2 |      5 |     10 | 2017-12-22 |       1 |
|      3 |      6 |     11 | 2017-12-13 |       1 |
|      4 |      7 |     12 | 2017-12-11 |       1 |
|      4 |      7 |     12 | 2017-12-18 |       1 |
```

Comment: your previous answer would've been sufficient.

Comment: Do we need the final Order BY statement at all?

Answer (score 2):

All you seem to need is an `ORDER BY` all the columns you mentioned in the order you mentioned them.

```
SELECT *
       FROM booksdb.dbo.books 
       ORDER BY bookid,
                pageid,
                textid,
                date;
```

Edit:

Note: If you want the order of the dates to show the youngest one first (e.g. 18-12-2017 before 11-12-2017), rather than the other way around, change the `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
       ORDER BY bookid,
                pageid,
                textid,
                date DESC;
```

(Note the `DESC` after `date`).

The desired result may contradict the description you gave and overall they leave room for interpretation regarding this point.

Comment: Wondering why it never occurred to me. In case I want to select the row with same bookid, pageid and textid with the most recent date?

Comment: @star_kid . . . This seems like the best answer to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Not sure about the `DESC`. If you look at the desired results it seems to be `ASC`. May depend on whether you emphasize "most recent" or "ascending" in "on the most recent date ascending"...

Comment: @stickybit . . . I was responding to the comment above.